# mistake in view-vote-counts privilege's documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, vote-count, documentation

The page https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts (and the corresponding page on the other SE sites) includes the following question and answer:

> #### When should I view vote counts?
>
> Statistically speaking, the vast majority of votes cast are upvotes. (Remember that downvoting costs a small amount of reputation and requires more reputation to earn as a privilege).

That doesn't seem to answer the question at all. Either the question or the answer should be changed so that the latter answers the former.

Comment: It's also incomplete now because downvoting doesn't *always* cost reputation now, since question downvotes are free.

Comment: @Daniel, true. I'd forgotten about that. Presumably anyone who might edit the documentation because of this question will notice your comment, so I don't think I need to add the gist of your comment into my question.

Comment: And also there should be an explanation **WHY this privilege exists at all**. Why the votes can't be visible to anyone.

Comment: @TomasTelensky, that's a separate issue; feel free to open a question for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the section entirely.

I'm honestly not sure what purpose that section served. It didn't really add anything to the subject -- IMO, the answer to that question is both entirely situational, and yet completely self-explanatory.

Assuming someone knows that the vote counts show the upvotes and downvotes separately (which the first section of the wiki covers), I think people are intelligent enough to figure out when they would want to view such a thing.

Comment: Thanks. +1. But I see it's removed on MSO, but not on all sites. Will it propagate? If not, this bug is still open.

Comment: @msh: The privilege wikis on MSO are periodically pushed to the other sites. I'm not sure how often that happens. (Maybe when a dev sees this question.)

Comment: And now I see it's propagated (at least to SO and Judaism.SE), so I'll accept this.